# NodeJS + MongoDb Multiply request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

working on a project with parsing the news portal news from various sites , Stack NodeJs + Express + MongoDb + ReactJS.

I think that I have a problem in your queries to the database for the home page to do more than 7 requests to get the news feed , 5 latest news in 4 different categories , popular videos and news browsing and so on.

The first version I think stupid

```
news.find({}, {....}).toArray(function(err, data) { 
    var NewsArray = data;
    politics.find({}, {....}).toArray(function(err, data) { 
      var politicsArray = data;
      .... / There is still a lot of requests , and in the end render with all the variables .
    }

  });
```

The second option did not even know could also not correct .

```
var _timer = 0,
     newsArray,
     politicsArray;


 news.find({}, {....}).toArray(function(err, data) { 
    newsArray = data;
    _timer++;
 })

 politics.find({}, {....}).toArray(function(err, data) { 
    politicsArray = data;
    _timer++;
 })

Another 6 queries ....

    renderToPage();

    function renderToPage(){
       if(_timer != 8(in example)){
           setTimeout(render, 100)
       } else {
           res.render(".....", {})
       }
    }
```

Please help fine form requests it to be nice and do not ship the server, and then the two queries chooses one category and the other 50 news items with a limit . Already DomContentLoaded 2,3 sec

Comment: Would you like to use `async.js`, a 3rd party node_module for async control flow?

Comment: look at promises (https://github.com/then/promise), or async, or something other flow control library. Just rewrite queries as parallel requests with some library or promises

Comment: And could you write an example to PROMIS , I have something I can not understand how to use them in this design ?

Comment: async.js - Thanks. I like it))